# When can all elements of $[A\to B]$ can be represented as computable functions?

Tags: computability-theory, lambda-calculus, domain-theory

(crosspost from math stackexchange)

While working through Barendreght's book on the Lambda Calculus, and Abramsky's notes on Domain Theory, I had the following realization:

It's often stated that Domain Theory provides a semantics for the untyped Lambda Calculus, and various other recursive constructions in computer science, by providing canonical (ie, minimal) fixpoints to domain equations like $X\cong[X\to X]_{\bot}$ (This is from "The Lazy Lambda Calculus", by Abramsky(1987), because the canonical fixpoint for $X\cong[X\to X]$ is the single-point set).

Now, one half of the isomorphism makes sense. Obviously every lambda-term either reduces to some suitable notion of normal form (giving rise to a function from lambda-terms to lambda-terms), or it doesn't reduce and can be identified with $\bot$.

However, I'm unsure about the second half of the isomorphism. Despite my reading so far, I still haven't found anything anywhere that has shown that every element in the space of Scott-continuous functions $[X\to X]$ corresponds to a lambda-term. It still looks possible (to me) that the lambda-terms form a subset of $[X\to X]$.

And generalizing further, if you have some domain like the lazy natural numbers (call it $N$), do all the elements of the function-space $[N\to N]$ correspond to a computable function? What conditions on domains $A$ and $B$ are sufficient (or necessary) for all elements of $[A\to B]$ to be represented as a computable function, and is there a standard reference for that information?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394272/how-do-we-know-whether-all-elements-of-a-to-b-can-be-represented-as-computab +1, but you should mention when you crosspost.

Comment: It is not usually the case that all elements of a function space are computable functions. The way computability is formulated in domain theory is "effective domain theory", and there are various formulations of it, involving picking an enumeration of a countable basis of a continuous dcpo $D$ such that certain operations are computable. It is not intended that Scott continuity be equivalent to computability, but to be an over-approximation, *i.e.* if a function is not Scott continuous, it's not computable *a fortiori*.

Comment: Also, it is *not* the case, nor intended to be the case, that each element of $[D \rightarrow D]$ corresponds to a $\lambda$-term. There are only countably many $\lambda$-terms, but $D$ has the cardinality of the continuum.